# My goal is to take element position from a directive and open a overLay on the same position.to do open the overlay i tried using this:

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-cdk

My goal is to take element position from a directive and open a overLay on the same position.to do open the overlay i tried using this:

```
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
      positionStrategy,
      scrollStrategy,
      hasBackdrop: true,
    });

   this.overlayRef
   .backdropClick()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.detachOverlay();
      });
  }

private attachOverlay(): void {
    if (!this.overlayRef.hasAttached()) {
      const periodSelectorPortal = new TemplatePortal(this.zisoCoachMark, this.vcr);

      this.overlayRef.attach(periodSelectorPortal);
    }
  }

  private detachOverlay(): void {
    if (this.overlayRef.hasAttached()) {
      this.overlayRef.detach();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question isn't really a question, it just describes your intent. You haven't mentioned what problem or difficulty you're having, so there's not much we can do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.